# onBlur management issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs

I have a one panel which can collapse and expand and also a I have added tag field in this panel so when i am open tag field picker after i am collapse panel than picker is not hiding in firefox but in chrome and IE works fine.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            reference: 'mypanel',
            padding: '0 15px',
            scrollable:true,
            width: 300,
            userCls: 'collapsible-panel border-right',
            title: 'My Panel',
            collapsible: {
                 direction: 'left',
                 collapsed: true,
                 dynamic:true
            },
            items: [{
                allowBlank: true,
                xtype: 'tagfield',
                margin: '5 5 5 5',
                fieldLabel: 'Tag Field 3',
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                filterPickList: true,
                emptyText: 'Multi Select...',
                name: 'tagField3'
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

I have debug internal code Extjs and found that on onBlur event hide picker of tag field it's work fine in Chrome and IE but in Firefox not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the lack of support for Firefox events [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event)\focusout. this confirms the source code ExtJS. [Pruf](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.1.0/classic/src/Focus.js.html)

```
// At this point only Firefox does not support focusin/focusout, see this bug:
// https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787
// TODO: Fix event order: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3123
handledDomEvents: ['focusin', 'focusout'],
```

ExtJs checks support for these events with help `Ext.supports.FocusinFocusoutEvents` property.